# design help on offline / reporting database

Tags: olap

We are considering to move away from having reports from a transactional database to an offline/ reporting database for our java web based project. Some ETL(like Kettle) to load the full/delta updates to offline database.

Reasons are obvious, to reduce load on transactional db & reporting performance.

Our outstanding questions are related to designing the offline database as i have no much knowledge on OLAP. Requirement is to have reports run by some report engine like Jasper/Pentaho, develop analytics and dashboards.

what is the best way to design offline/reporting

1) One big flat table? -  I am sure this very bad idea.

2) Multiple flat tables. I mean multiple denormalized tables. Idea is to de-normalize the related tables and link other de-normalized tables to get detailed reports.

And any idea how we can handle summaries?

3) Star schema, facts and dimensions.

One dumb question here: can we have all other detail columns in a fact table along with additive measures(summaries or aggregated data)

Is there a an tool to denormalize data from a set of normalised tables?

Thanks in advance.
Pradeep

Comment: pls see my answer here for a starting point: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45655/what-are-measures-and-dimensions-in-cubes/45669#45669

Comment: also, get the book Agile Data Warehouse Design. Cheap and good.